# Find all element within namespace

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have a xml with multiple namespaces.
I want to iterate over element where namespace = 'http://ns.example.com/xmto/'

I am using Python 3.4 with ElementTree

this code shows element1:

```
tree.findall("{http://ns.example.com/xpto/}element1")
```

I would like to find all element with this namespace.
Something like:

```
tree.findall("{http://ns.example.com/xpto/}:*")
```

Is it possible?
Or the only way is to check the element.tag on every element?

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use `lxml.etree`, you could use XPath's [namespace-uri()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/namespace-uri) function, something like this:

```
elements = tree.xpath('//*[namespace-uri() = "http://ns.example.com/xpto/"]')
```

Unfortunately, the XPath support in `xml.etree` does not support the `namespace-uri` function. Possibly someone else will chime in with a solution that works with the native xml module, but I enjoy working with the xpath support `lxml`.

Comment: Thanks, I will use lxml while i cannot find a native solution.